# Breaking and incomplete tweets using tweepy

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

Am trying to collect a huge number of tweets using tweepy and python but is giving me a broken and incomplete tweet which end with \u2026. Also am just interested on the tweets only bt some tweets come along with urls and other junks that i dont need. Pls help.

Pls how can I post an indented code in this forum as I cant find any toolbar.

Comment: Hello! To post code, just paste it in.  You should see a `{}` button to automatically indent it. If not, just post it anyway and someone else will format it for you.

Comment: Ok thank you Terence